# CSS: Vertical centering in a position:absolute div

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment

I have this code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">something</div>
</div>
```

The parent should be 200px width and height, and the child 100px width and height. The parent is also set to `position:absolute`. Is it possible to horizontaly and verticaly center the `child` relative to the `parent` and how?

The result: If you set black background to the parent and white to the child, the whole thing should look like there is a white square with a large black border.

Static margins and paddings are out of the question since the size of the child will change dynamically.

---

That might not be the proper solution, but what I am actually trying to achieve is a black square which I can change the size of with jQuery and it will stay at the same absolute position, like it is being scaled from the center, not from the top left corner.

I thought I could set the position of a parent and let the child center horizontaly and verticaly auto while changing it's size, so I would get the proper 'scale'-like effect.

Comment: So do you want a pure CSS solution or a jQuery one?

Comment: A working one really. The real problem is that when I animate the border from 0 to 10 for example, and I animate the top and left to -10 from their current position it should stay at the same place, but doesn't.. There's a weird 1 pixel buffer where the whole square goes bottom-right then top-left then bottom-right again (to the correct position). I'm pretty sure it comes from the rounding that occurs on each tick when jQuery calculates the values for `.animate()`.

Comment: _"the child 100px width and height"_ contradicts _"the size of the child will change dynamically"_.

Comment: It wont change, but the border will, so the effect is similar, just wanted to sound simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [jQuery UI position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) API to position the child div at center and then on [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) based on `border-width` you should change the `top` and `left` accordingly.

*Try out the DEMO to understand the below code* [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/vK3ay/1/)

After Animation:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">something</div>
</div>

<button>Animate</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    positionChild();
});


function positionChild() {
    $( ".child" ).position({
                of: $( ".parent" ),
                my: "center center",
                at: "center center"
    });
}

$('button').click (function () {
    $('.child').animate({'border-width': 47, top: '-=46', left: '-=46'}, 1000);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent { 
    position: absolute;  
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    background-color: black; 
    top: 100px; 
    left: 100px; 
}

.child { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #c2c2c2; 
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? In mine (Google Chrome) it still wiggles 1px - just like my original problem.. I just tested, it wiggles in Firefox too.

Comment: I tested it in FF 10.0.2, Chrome 17.0.963.56 and it seems fine. Is that 1px before animation or after animation?

Comment: All the time.. in my snippet it is at the end. I wonder if I could make `.animate()` tick 10 times and animate 10px, so each tick will be exactly 1px - I could rule out the rounding issue I'm thinking of..

Comment: @Tony I am still trying to understand this 1px you are talking about... Do you see the image? Where is it 1px off?

Comment: @SKS I am using the same chrome version as you and I think I see the problem he is talking about. It might help to look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/VGkEz/3/) I have grow and shrink buttons so that you can click them a few times in a row to see what is happening. If I am right, at the very start of the animation the inner box looks like it moves 1px up and left, and at the end it appears to move 1px down and right. Tony am I right?

Comment: I've recorded the flicker/wiggle and lowered the animation duration to 3000 ms: http://www65.zippyshare.com/v/1587892/file.html Yes @TheWaxMann exactly.

Comment: slowing it down to 3000 and using developer tools at the same time helped me figure it out: the resizing and the moving are not done at the exact same time using the .animate method. The grow button on my example alters the margin first, then the size, this makes the wiggle you are seeing.

Comment: Slowing the animation down even further to 10000 really makes it stand out if you haven't seen it yet. I am not sure there is anything you can do about it though, other than make the animation fast enough so you don't notice it. It is just the way the .animate method works

Comment: @TheWaxMann It is not the animate.. It is just that two css property cannot be animated at the same time.. It is going to be progressive and I think you need to speed up the transition so it doesn't wiggle.

Comment: Yes, I made a predefined function that updates all values simultaneously and all is ok. At least we found the problem. Could anyone recommend a plugin or a version of `.animate()` where I could supply a `step` callback which will be called each tick, so I could update all values at once in there.. use the animate just for the ticks.

Comment: @Tony I don't think you will find one, because each tick is calculated based on animation speed and the level of transition.

Comment: Yeah I saw.. I am trying to trick it though.. `$('<div/>').animate({'null': 1000}, {duration: 50, step: function(now) { $('body').append(now+', '); }});` now in the tick function I could do whatever I want simultaneously and I could calculate the value based on the desired start and end values according to the `now` which is being transitioned from 0 to 1000.

Comment: This is unbelievable :X The problem occurs even when using CSS3 transitions *omg*

Answer (score 1):

Since you edited your post to include jQuery:

```
   var c = $('.child'),
       cw = c.width(),
       ch = c.height(),
       hh = ch/2;

c.css({'position' : 'relative' , 'top' : '50%' , 'margin' : '0 auto' , 'margin-top' : '-' + hh + 'px' });
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/Fmv8P/)

Adjust the height and width of each div and re-run to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

set `line-height:200px` to parent and `display:inline-block` to child. you need  to set `line-height: 20px` or something else and `vertical-align:middle` to child.

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/rHrK3/14/)

look at this code:

```
.parent{
    position:absolute; 
    height:200px; 
    width:200px; 
    background:red;
    line-height:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
.child{
    background:blue; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:20px;  /* or something else  */
}
```